# Does VirtualBox "Export Appliance" feature also export the snapshots?

Tags: backup, windows-7, virtualization, virtualbox

How can I export/copy a virtual machine with all its snapshots and move it to another machine? Do I have to use some CLI commands or **Export Appliance** will be sufficient for this?

VirtualBox 4.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone a VM with all snapshiots over the GUI using the option "Clone everything".

> [right mouseclick] VM -> Clone... -> [button] Next -> [radio button] Full clone -> [radio button] **Everything** -> [button] Clone

[image]

Comment: This option duplicates a virtual machine but doesn't create an exported appliance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transplant a complex VM wholesale to a different system it's usually possible to just zip up the directory, move it to the other system, unpack it in the right place and double click on the `.vbox` file to register the VM.

If you choose `Export Appliance` it will just export the VM containing the last state the VM was.

Comment: This is true.. but if you are trying to create a all in 1 solution, where you want to be able to 1. create a automated backup of the VM 2. be able to bring up the VM alongside the backup the VM and 3. transfer the VM from one computer to another, copy pasting the VM folder wont work. The UUIDs dont change when you copy paste the VM folder. As a result you wont be able to bring up the backup of the VM and the VM itself on the same computer

Comment: Furthermore, cloning a virtual machine to computers in the same network doesn't change the MAC addresses of the Ethernet adapters. If you then connect these adapters to the same network, weird things will happen, such as connecting to the wrong machine.